# Kafka Debezium Db2 connection throwing error on Windows 10

Tags: apache-kafka, windows-10, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying for a Debezium connection to DB2 through Kafka connect and its throwing the below error. The same setup for mysql works in Mac but unable to get it worked in Windows10. Any pointers.

```
C:\Tools\Kafka.\bin\windows\connect-standalone.bat .\config\connect-standalone.properties .\config\connect-debezium-db2.properties
```

Error i am getting is

```
ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone) java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Trailing char < > at index 15: C:\Tools\kafka\
```

Full error desc

```
ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone) java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Trailing char < > at index 15: C:\Tools\kafka\
    at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:229)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:137)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.<init>(DelegatingClassLoader.java:433)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:325)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:261)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:209)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:202)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:79) Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Trailing char < > at index 15: C:\Tools\kafka\
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    ... 9 more Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Trailing char < > at index 15: C:\Tools\kafka\
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:191)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at java.io.File.toPath(File.java:2234)
    at org.reflections.vfs.SystemDir.lambda$getFiles$2(SystemDir.java:37)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:260)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.scan(DelegatingClassLoader.java:441)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.lambda$scan$0(Reflections.java:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: If you have the option I'd recommend running it under WSL - you'll have far fewer problems: https://www.confluent.co.uk/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/

Comment: I saw that blog but unfortunately i do not have at the moment.

Comment: What is the path value it is complaining about `InvalidPathException: Trailing char` ?  Try fixing that first.

Comment: @mao - where do i find that? The error do not show the path value. Updated the fill error in the question.

Comment: It mentions path "C:\Tools\kafka\" . Examine all the config files. Try without the trailing backslash, taking a backup of any file before you change it, in case you need to revert.

Comment: @mano - C:\Tools\Kafka is the folder where i am executing the command. So counting 15 characters will end in \connect-standalone.properties. Updated the error in the above code with folder details.

Comment: The error is with the period in `.\bin`, which should be only `C:\Tools\Kafka\bin\windows\...`, otherwise, `cd` to the bin\windows folder and then reference `..\config` files

Comment: Its crazy i tried everything including the above.....nothing is working.